# Impossible to track visits/referral from an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, analytics

We have created a website that sales online ferry tickets.
We also created an affiliate system and propose our booking engine to third party websites (via an iframe).

Ex: http://travelq.ru/s-krita-na-santorini-na-parome/.

Iframe url: https://www.ferriesingreece.com/affiliate_engine_small.php

Every time a user is searching from this engine (in iframe), there is a form submission to https://www.ferriesingreece.com/redirecting.php?aff=affiliate_name.

Problem:
We can not track visits (as referrals or as new visits) from third party websites.
Analytics do not count the clicks that comes from the iframe.
We thought it was an issue of the submitting form. So, we added a direct link to https://www.ferriesingreece.com in the iframe to test it and the result is the same. Nothing is counted.
Finally we think that this is logically happening because the iframe content belongs to https://www.ferriesingreece.com, and analytics record that the user is already in our site, so it shows up as a user is navigating in our site. (not a new visit, not a referral.)

Is there any way to track those visits/referals from an iframe?

Is there a way to add analytics code somehow in this iframe and be able to record only the clicks and the parent website as referal?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use UTM URL parameters for this. For example, if you add the parameters `utm_source=form&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=affiliate` to your form's target, the visit should* show up in your analytics report as a referral from the source 'form'. It will also show up the 'campaigns' section of your report.

Read more about UTM here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

The full target link to your form would look like this: `https://www.ferriesingreece.com/redirecting.php?aff=affiliate_name&utm_source=form&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=affiliate`